# Pass SelectList "SelectedValue" to Controller Action Method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, selectlist

I have a registration form which displays a users Name (textbox), Email (textbox) and Division (SelectList).  The Name and Email are pre-populated (I'm using Windows Authentication, Intranet app), and I want to send the SelectedValue from the DropDown to my controller as an Int32, I don't want to send the entire SelectList back.  This list is small now, but will grow to considerable size.

I a class called `RegistrationViewModel`, it contains public properties for these fields.  However, when I use `SelectList` for the DivisionList, I receive this error: `No parameterless constructor defined for this object.`.

If i change the Type, it works no problem, but Division is null or 0.  Is there a way to pass the SelectedValue from a DropDown to a Controller Action method as a Int32?

## Edit 1:

I'm not really sure what I'm doing, I've been using MVC for about 48 hours, watched the PDF, TechEd, and TechDays videos.

My apologies, here is my controller code:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Register(RegistrationViewModel rvm)
{
    IApplicationContext context = ContextRegistry.GetContext();
    IValidationErrors errors = new ValidationErrors();

    IValidator validator = (IValidator)context.GetObject("RegistrationValidator");
    bool valid = validator.Validate(rvm, errors);

    if (valid)
        repo.SaveRegistration();
    else
        ViewData["DivisionList"] = repo.GetDivisions();

    return View(rvm);
}
```

`RegistrationViewModel` Class

```
public class RegistrationViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    //public SelectList DivisionList { get; private set; }
    public int Division { get; set; }    
}
```

Here's the view

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" 
MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" 
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<RegistrationViewModel>" %>

<%@ Import Namespace="Project1.Entities"%>
<%@ Import Namespace="Project1.Models"%>

<asp:Content ID="registerTitle" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Register
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="registerContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
...
    <% using (Html.BeginForm())
       { %>
        <div>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Account Information</legend>
                <p>
                    <label for="name">Name:</label>
                    <%= Html.TextBox("Name", User.Identity.Name.GetDisplayName()) %>
                    <%= Html.ValidationMessage("username") %>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="email">Email:</label>
                    <%= Html.TextBox("email", User.Identity.Name.GetEmailFromLogin()) %>
                    <%= Html.ValidationMessage("email") %>
                </p>              
                <p>
                    <label for="division">Division:</label>
                    <%= Html.DropDownList("DivisionList", ViewData["DivisionList"] as SelectList)%>
                    <%= Html.ValidationMessage("confirmPassword") %>
                </p>
                <p>                
                    <input type="submit" value="Register" />
                </p>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    <% } %>
</asp:Content>
```

## Edit 2:

Eilon: Here is what I changed it too:

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Register()
{
  ViewData["DivisionList"] = repo.GetDivisions();
  return View();
}
```

View:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("DivisionValue", ViewData["DivisionList"] as SelectList)%>
```

I recieve this exception:
There is no ViewData item with the key 'DivisionValue' of type 'IEnumerable'.

When I updated the View to this:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("DivisionList", ViewData["DivisionList"] as SelectList)%>
```

It works just great!  It only seems to work if all the "Division" items named identically.  If I change the name the View crashes or the ViewModel "Division" property is sent as 0.

Why is that?

Comment: Please show us your controller action code. How are you passing the value of the email textbox?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **RegistrationViewModel** type should contain a simple-typed property such as:

```
public string DivisionValue { get; set; }
```

Or change the type to int, DateTime, or whatever the appropriate type is.

In HTML and HTTP the only thing that gets posted back for a drop down list is the name of the field and the selected value.

To get everything to match up you also need to change the view to render a different input name for the drop down list:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("DivisionValue", ViewData["DivisionList"] as SelectList)%>
```

Notice that I'm using "DivisionValue" is the *value* of the list, and *DivisionList* as the list of all available items.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just be more explicit with the `SelectList` type. I'd suggest creating the `SelectList` in the controller action and forget about casting it in the view. My code works like this (CRUD Edit page):

..in the Action:

```
            ViewData["WorkType.ID"] = new SelectList(this._vacancySvc.GetVacancyWorkTypes(),
            "ID", "Name", ViewData["WorkType.ID"] ?? vacancy.WorkType.ID);
```

..and in the view:

```
<p><% =Html.Encode("Work Type:") %><br />
            <% =Html.DropDownList("Worktype.ID")%><span class="smallgrey">(required)</span><br />
```

.. you can see that either the initial selection (from DB) is persisted or the ViewData from post backs (like if the form fails validation) thru the use of the [null coalescing operator][1] (??).

Moreover, if i refactored this code, i'd prob like to use a ViewModel object like you are. 
The only thing is: (1) you'd never need to reference the ViewModel `SelectList` property in the view coz MVC auto binds this for us by the `Html.DropDownList()` overload.. and (2) i'd still need to ref the ViewData in the action anyway to get the selected value from a failed validation post back so what's the point really??