# Trouble with MVC Dropdownlist, not sure how to set it up

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to create a dropdownlist with the ability to set the ID as well (as I have two going from the same viewbag). something like

```
@Html.DropDownList("startTimes", (SelectList)ViewBag.times, new { @class = "date" })

@Html.DropDownList("endTimes", (SelectList)ViewBag.times, new { @class = "date" })
```

Right now, I have

> ViewBag.times = getTimeList();
>
> ```
>     private List<SelectListItem> getTimeList()
>     {
>         List<SelectListItem> times = new List<SelectListItem>();
>         for (int Minutes = 60; Minutes < 770; Minutes += 30)
>         {
>             TimeSpan TS = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Minutes);
>             String TSString = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", TS.Hours, TS.Minutes);
>             SelectListItem item = new SelectListItem();
>             item.Text = TSString;
>             item.Value = TS.Minutes.ToString();
>             times.Add(item);
>         }
>
>         return times;
>     }
> ```

But I am getting an error: Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go

```
@Html.DropDownList("endTimes", new SelectList(ViewBag.times, "Value", "Text"), new { @class = "date" })
```

As stated by the error you need to create a new `SelectList` for this to work and not just cast from your existing enumerable. The `DropDownList` helper overloads should show you that.

You could also have googled the question and found the answer yourself, like in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208924/asp-net-mvc-select-list) for example.

UPDATE:

Just reread your question now and you are talking about setting the `id` for the dropdownlist, that is not actually related to your error. The `id` will be set from the first parameter to the `DropDownList` helper (it is the "name" parameter in the method).