# No parameterless constructor defined for this object. when dealing with MultiSelectList

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, models

this is probably the most frustrating error I have ran into.

I have an entity Channel that has a has-many relationship with Ad Slots. On creation a user can select which Ad Slots they want to belong to their channel.

I have this model:

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Name")]
public string ChannelName { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Description")]
public string ChannelDescription { get; set; }

//TODO: Add Sub Publisher Drop-Down

[Required(ErrorMessage = "You must select at least one Ad Slot.")]
[Display(Name = "Ad Slot(s)")]
public MultiSelectList AdSlots { get; set; }
```

and this in my view:

```
<div class="field">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ChannelName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ChannelName)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ChannelName)
</div>
<div class="field">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ChannelDescription)
    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.ChannelDescription, new { @class = "description" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ChannelDescription)
</div>
<div class="field">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.AdSlots)
    @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.AdSlots, new MultiSelectList(new[] { new { Value = "", Text = "" } }, "Value", "Text", new[] { "" }), new { Class = "multiselect", Multiple = "multiple", Size = 12 })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.AdSlots)
</div>
```

This is my controller actions that handle the processing:

```
//GET: /publishers/channels/new
public ActionResult New()
{
    return View();
}

//POST: /publishers/channels/new
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult New(Models.Channels.Create channelModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Channel
        Core.Linq.APMaster.Channel channel = new Core.Linq.APMaster.Channel();
        channel.PublisherId = PublisherId;
        channel.Guid = Guid.NewGuid();
        channel.ChannelName = channelModel.ChannelName;
        channel.ChannelDescription = channelModel.ChannelDescription;
        channel.DateCreated = DateTime.UtcNow;
        channel.UserCreated = PublisherId;
        //TODO: Fix CreatedFromIP data-type bug.
        channel.CreatedFromIP = 0;
        channel.IsActive = true;
        channel.IsCustom = false;
        myDBContext.APMasterDBC.Channels.InsertOnSubmit(channel);

        // Ad Slots
        foreach (SelectListItem adSlotModel in channelModel.AdSlots)
        {
            Core.Linq.APMaster.ChannelAdSlot channelAdSlot = new Core.Linq.APMaster.ChannelAdSlot();
            channelAdSlot.ChannelId = channel.ChannelId;
            channelAdSlot.AdSlotId = int.Parse(adSlotModel.Value);
            channelAdSlot.IsActive = true;
            myDBContext.APMasterDBC.ChannelAdSlots.InsertOnSubmit(channelAdSlot);

        }

        myDBContext.APMasterDBC.SubmitChanges();

        TempData["flash"] = "Your Channel Has Been Created";

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    else
    {
        TempData["flash"] = "Your Channel Has Not Been Created";
    }

    return View(channelModel);
}
```

As you can see I am trying to insert many Ad Slots from the MultiSelectList. However I keep getting: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

Does anyone know why this is? Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? Why is it throwing this?

Answer (score 1):

I found out thanks to this post:
[Pass SelectList "SelectedValue" to Controller Action Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930560/pass-selectlist-selectedvalue-to-controller-action-method)

That the model type has to be simple (e.g. int[]) and then I use ViewData to populate the list.